# Frond-end разработчик за 17 месяцев

Tags: html, php, html5, javascript, css

Доброго времени суток.

Предисловие.

У меня есть в запасе 17 месяцев до окончания вуза, после которого я выйду в свободное плавание. И за это время я хочу набраться знаний и опыта в front-end разработке, на такой уровень, чтобы можно было устроиться работать Junior-ом в какую нибудь фирму.

До этого момента я не знал, чем хочу заниматься по жизни, метался от одного к другому.
В поисках себя я наверно всю свою сознательную жизнь, еще в детстве я умудрялся ходить на три кружка сразу (по собственному желанию).

Год назад я открыл для себя веб разработку, начал изучать, но где-то через неделю,  я   снова переключился на другое занятие как мне тогда показалось, более интересное. 
Два месяца увлечения прошли быстро и я забросил, к тому моменту про веб я уже и  забыл.

На просторах интернета все всегда советуют заниматься тем к чему душа лежит, и только тогда будишь счастлив, но сами в большинстве случаев работают на работе не приносящей удовольствия.

От веб разработки не сказать, прям, оторваться не могу, но интересно прописывать строчки кода, а потом смотреть результат и если все работает, так как ты написал это конечно приносит удовольствие (да и тема интернета мне очень близка). Можно сказать у меня это получается но прям, большого удовольствия не приносит но интерес есть. Хотя если у меня появиться в будущем дело моей жизни я думаю, оно станет моим хобби, а потом я постараюсь сделать его своей любимой работой.
Но времени выбирать нет, его и так слишком мало.

У вас я хочу попросить совета, как лучше мне действовать что-бы добиться своих целей, может кто-то поделиться своим опытом становления веб-разработчиком.

Ниже я хочу написать список технологий которые я собираюсь "выучить" и источники откуда я буду черпать знания.

1.Основы основ протокол TCP/IP или как работает Интернет
Понимание работы HTTP

а) http://www.ofnet.ru/osnovy-interneta/tcpip.html(для примера)

2.HTML 4, XHTML, HTML 5 + CSS 2,3

a)Даже боюсь произносить эту фамилию в интернете зная какой бугурт она за собой повлечет, но все же Видео курс Евгения Попова HTML и CSS базовые курсы. Курс по HTML я уже прошел, для новичка очень понятно и доступно все объясняет.

б) После собираюсь полностью проштудировать http://htmlbook.ru получая новые знания об HTML и CSS и закрепляя старые после курса Попова.

в) Табличная, блочная, адаптивная верстка.

3.JavaScript+jquery

а)Видео курс Попова JavaScript+jquery

б)http://javascript.ru/

4.php+mysql самые основы.

a) http://www.php5.ru/

б) http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.php

Вот вроде все, а если может где-то я ошибаюсь, прошу подправить.

Надеюсь на ваши советы.

Comment: ну вы же понимаете, что за 17 месяцев с таким багажом ничего не получится? Лет за десять — ещё куда ни шло. Если у вас хватит смелости признать, что все предыдущие действия, направленные на быстрое достижение видимости результата, были ошибочными, то года за три до джуниора дорастёте.

Comment: @stros1993 раз Вы несколько раз пробовали и у Вас не получается, оно не "затягивает", тогда это не Ваше. Вы будете на работе мучиться.

Comment: Вставлю свои 5 копеек как человек, который сейчас находится на пути становления: забудьте про всякие видеокурсы Евгения Попова, не тратьте на них время, читайте умные книжки и много практикуйтесь. Думаю, 17 месяцев для того, чтобы стать джуниором будет достаточно. Удачи!

Comment: @andreyqin, вы же понимаете, что именно из-за попова теперь потребуется гораздо больше времени

Comment: Проще сразу застрелиться чем учить фронтенд 10 лет. Веб не стоит на месте, учиться придется постоянно. codecademy.com для начала, codeschool.com продолжить, найти пару заказчиков из местных предпринимателей у которых нет сайта, за пару месяцев сваять им визитки, понять в каком направлении хочется развиваться, смотреть awwwards.com, читать зарубежных авторов по теме, смотреть что нужно джуниору и стучаться в компании

Comment: зачем фронтенду php ?

Comment: Успешнее разбираться и править неразделенный код php+html; поможет лучше освоить Ajax; работодатели могут зачесть это в плюс или вовсе выставить требования к минимальным знаниям; для общего образования; я уж не говорю о требованиях типа "и швец и жнец, и на дуде игрец"(работа в фотошоп, умение рисовать и делать макеты, быть дизайнером) у некоторых лиц.

Comment: @eicto, ну как же, шаблончики всякие) вывод данных вы чем будете делать? :)

Comment: а вывод данных разве не backend-разработчик будет делать?

Comment: @Елена Левина окай, бекенд мне вернет json например, библиотекой шаблонизатора, написанном для пехепе, я это все выведу куда надо и соберу страницу исходя из условий и данных которые получу.  
вопрос про то, что это можно собрать js не стоит :) будем считать, что js неможно :) Да и собрирать большой сайт js будет накладно для пользователя и для поддержки/разработки

Comment: @thunder, посмотрите в сторону ASP.NET, там frond-end разработчики напрямую практически не соприкасаются с back-end.
Аналогично, при работе с шаблонизаторами frond-end разработчик может вообще не задаваться вопросом на чем написана серверная часть: php или python.

Comment: ну вообще его вообще не должно касаться на чем написан бекенд, я про это и не говорил) я говорил, что ему вернется ответ от бекенда жеж. и отвечал на вопрос нафига пхп во фронтенде может понадобиться.  
я писал про то что: я пехепе разработчик, у меня есть Index.php который управляет запросами пользователя, всякие там ЧПУ и т.п., сама страница генерится на основе шаблонизатора типа twig/smarty/etc...

Comment: @thunder, front-end developer и работает с шаблонами twig/smarty/etc Шаблоны имеют свой синтаксис и PHP код там не должен появляться. Если появился, значит это ошибка back-end разработчика.

Comment: По поводу back-end.

Думаю ТС в любом случае должен что-то уметь делать там. В конце-концов где он возьмет back-end разработчиков для своих тренировок в эти 17 месяцев?

Comment: @uzumaxy толи я както криво объясняю, то ли что... в САМОМ шаблоне и не будет пехепе. но

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
    ));
    
    echo $twig->render('index.html', array('name' => 'Fabien'));

сам пехепе то будет в файле index.php, который будет подключать шаблонизатор и другую модную фигню, о чем спор-то? что вообзще нигде во фронтенде не должно быть пхп?? :)

Comment: @thunder, даже не знаю, что и сказать :) В последнее время как-то всё через rest-api, шаблоны на клиенте ангуляр обрабатывает, всё просто, быстро и красиво. Где сложности-то? На сервере тоже js, если что :)

Comment: @thunder, в Вашем примере зачем верстальщику вообще открывать "index.php"? Он будет работать только с "index.html".

> что вообзще нигде во фронтенде не должно быть пхп?? :)
index.php - back-end
index.html - frond-end
Да, нигде во фронтенде не должно быть PHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ох, ну ладно, царского пути не скажу, но со своего небольшого опыта могу посоветовать немного:

Построение пользовательских интерфейсов:

1) Самые азы HTML учится на сайте постройка: http://www.postroika.ru/html/content2.html

2) Идем на сайт intuit.ru и углубляемся в HTML:

- [Введение в HTML](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/33/33/info)
- [Основы работы с HTML](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1102/134/info)
- [Спецификация языка HTML](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/11/11/info) - это
     главные знания
- [HTML 4.0](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/certification/4485/1010/info) - это итоговый зачет на
     хорошее владение HTML, надо
     постараться сдать на 4 или 5

3) Там же в CSS уходим

- [Основы работы с CSS](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1101/135/info)
- [Применение каскадных таблиц стилей (CSS)](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/34/34/info)
- [Основы работы с XHTML и CSS](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/2261/159/info)
- [Спецификация CSS2](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/90/90/info) - это главные
     знания
- [CSS 1.0](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/certification/976/169/info) - это итоговый зачет на
     хорошее владение CSS, надо
     постараться сдать на 4 или 5.

4) Далее читаем учебник на htmlbook по HTML и по CSS.

После этого можно считать, что у вас есть уверенные знания и остается набивать руку в верстке. Так же советую почитать книгу "Не заставляйте меня думать"

После этого переходим к программированию, лучше сначала JavaScript:

- Девид Фланаган - "JavaScript.
     Подробное руководство"
- Стефанов - JavaScript. Шаблоны.
- Маклафлин - Изучаем Ajax.
- Так же знакомимся с библиотекой
     JQuery, можно по книге или по
     документации.

После этого можно переходить к изучению PHP + база данных.

- Д.В.Котеров, А.Ф.Костарев - PHP5 в
     подлиннике
- Знакомимся со всякими Joomla,
     Wordpress, Drupal, DLE и т.д.
- Знакомимся с фреймворками.
- (Может кто-то тут предложит лучшие варианты и источники PHP + БД)

Насчет Попова - он может Вам помочь понять быстрее что-то, но последней инстанцией его считать не стоит. Посмотрите, но потом все таки доведите знания до годной планки литературой. А так же особо не верьте в его пресловутые 20%/80%, хоть запоминать все наизусть не надо, но прочитать стоит все 99%.
По поводу сетей, стоит почитать клиент-серверную архитектуру, но поначалу сильно углубляться не стоит. Т.к. в этом не будет большого смысла.

Это начало, дальше уже пойдет более серьезная литература и больше статьи, которую я думаю вы сможете найти сами(алгоритмизация, шифрование, проектирование БД, Apache/nginx, FastCGI, highload и т.д.).

Ну и главное не забывать, что практика важнее всякой теории и иметь хоть какое-то более менее потфолио будет плюсом.
И еще, не надо все пытаться выучить наизусть, главное прочитать и постаратся запомнить основные моменты. Что-то непременно забудется, именно поэтому самый главный помощник - это справочник под рукой.

Comment: простите, в php не спец, но знакомые php-программеры книгу Котерова и Костарева костерят почём зря, утверждая, что там множество фактических ошибок и отсутствие подачи культуры разработки. Кто прав?

Comment: Они безусловно правы, но к сожалению мне пока не довелось видеть ни одной нормальной русскоязычной книги по PHP. Не говоря уже об отсутствии книг по более продвинутым техниках построения сложных приложений. Из прочитанных мною, это был самый лучший вариант + некоторые вещи пригодились(запрет кэширования например). Фактически именно поэтому я первым предлагаю изучить JavaScript, а не PHP. Если кто-то скажет что-то дельное по этому пункту, буду только рад))

Comment: >ни одной нормальной русскоязычной книги по PHP

ну русскоязычные-то наверное есть. Я имею в виду переводы. В случае с обучением не имеет значения, где написана книга - в России или за рубежом

Comment: зачем программисту русскоязычная книга?на буржуйском пишете,на буржуйском и читайте!

Comment: @rusbaron ТС вообще-то студент. Вряд ли его познания в английском достаточны для чтения профлитературы

Comment: по js на самом деле тоже достаточно мало хороших материалов на русском. Хотя казалось бы… Так что приходится уметь читать на буржуйском. Но вот наблюдение: когда читаешь технические статьи, обычно вообще не сразу замечаешь, на каком языке они написаны. Что русский, что английский, испанский … на китайский может ещё можно внимание обратить из-за непривычных русскому глазу иероглифов, но и это порой не мешает воспринимать информацию. Код-то всё равно на знакомом языке.

Comment: я выпустившийся студент,буквально в этом году и могу сказать,что проф литературу начал читать с 3ьего курса на буржуйском.Было тяжело,но терпимо.Само собой словарь нужен,но читать можно и знания черпать тоже.А перевести могут и через одно место,что часто и происходит.
По моему технический английский не оч сложный,в отличии от художественного(Книгу по php на инглише норм читал,а вот толкиена так и не смог главу прочесть,на каждом пятом слове в словарь)

Comment: @rusbaron это скорее исключение чем правило. Хуже того, многим вообще книгу читать в лом, хотят посмотреть пару-тройку видео с Ютуба и сразу стать профи. Обращаясь к примеру ТСа - как вы думаете, почему чувак вопреки всем словам хочет учиться по видеокурсам Попова? Потому что легко, не напряжно, не нужно ничего читать и вникать. Ну а что касается результата такой учебы...люди в глубине души склонны верить в чудеса.

Answer (score 3):

Как понять ваш список? Вы собрались полтора года читать сайты и смотреть курсы?

Найдите себе работу/подработку/стажировку. По своему опыту, ничего особо не зная, но умея разбираться - это реально. Тем более, что через полтора года придя с дипломом и без опыта на собеседование, вас ждет разочарование. Да и джуниором с дипломом как то не сильно хорошо, имхо.

Comment: >придя с дипломом из без опыта на собеседование, вас ждет разочарование

Ну не факт. Я, например, устраивался на свою первую работу именно таким образом - с дипломом, без опыта, да ещё и после армии. Однако проблем это не создало

Comment: @DreamChild, конечно, не факт. Но вероятность большая. Я сейчас на 5 курсе учусь, работаю с третьего, но иногда думаю что разбираться надо было начинать пораньше.

Comment: да ладно вам - сейчас на джуниоров вообще едва ли не всех подряд берут. Доходит даже до того, что какой-нибудь отродясь нигде не работавший школьник из Усть-Жопинска приходит на собеседование и сообщает, что меньше чем за 70тыр он на этой работе не будет заниматься даже  ничегонеделанием

Comment: ага, но такие джуниорами и остаются :) опять-таки, в большинстве случаев.

Comment: ну ТСу-то об этом думать еще рано - он пока еще даже не джуниор)

Comment: Зря вы спорите. В каждом городе по-своему стоит вопрос относительно трудоустройства студентов ИТ специальностей. Где-то с руками отрывают, а где-то по десятку людей на место.

Answer (score 2):

Курсы на http://www.w3schools.com/, заодно и английский подтяните.

Comment: Хороший сайт, правда мне кажется он хорош больше как справочник.
Ну еще добавлю такой справочник PHP: http://moxie.oswego.edu/doc/php/

Comment: Хороший сайт? Да его матерят в любом приличном месте.
http://www.w3fools.com/
https://www.google.ru/search?q=why+w3schools+is+bad

Comment: Правда конкретикой и объективностью эти приличные места не страдают, целенаправленная критика на минусы. У меня есть свое мнение и впечатление от пользования тем или иным сайтом. Я внимательно ознакомился с приведенным текстом и не нашел его убедительным, хотя отчасти они правы. Но так же они и не правы, не приведя нормальное сравнение плюсов и минусов.
http://aspektas.com/blog/w3fools-a-foolish-attack-on-w3schoolscom/

Comment: Проходить какие-то странные левые сертификационные тесты на этом сайте никто никого не заставляет, зато информация изложена хорошо и по полочкам, дается основное и без перегрузки деталями, есть песочница с примерами, в которые можно потыкать палочкой и посмотреть что как работает, и есть простые тесты на проверку базовых знаний по каждому разделу, тесты эти могут представлять сложность разве что для новичка, но ТС вроде и есть новичок.

Comment: Сомнительный ресурс, который как известно ничего общего с w3c не имеет, зато в гугле крайне популярен. Неизвестно, кто стоит за этим сайтом, какая у этих людей квалификация и цели.

Answer (score 1):

А вообще вот что. Судя по упоминаниям нечистого, видеоуроки вы любите. Так смотрите кошерные видеоуроки: http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast . И для здоровья полезнее, и некоторую культуру всё-таки прививает.

Comment: @Елена Левина, ага. Может ему сразу на ASP.NET перейти? Там точно научится культурно писать код.

Answer (score -1):

По [Javascript](http://itvdn.com/ru/video/javascript-essential)`y, я бы посоветовал видео Охрименко

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1638/Что-делать-когда-просят-ссылки-а-потом-получают-ссылки